# economical way of scaling a php+mysql website

Tags: mysql, ajax, amazon-web-services, scalability, redundancy

My partner and I are trying to start a website hosted in cloud.  It has pretty heavy ajax traffic and the backend handles money transactions so we need ACID in some of the DB tables.

Currently everything is running off a single server.  Some of the AJAX traffic are cached in text files.

Question:

1. What's the best way to scale the database server?  I thought about moving mysql to separate instances and do master-master duplication.  However this seems tough and I heard I might lose ACID properties even with InnoDB?  Is Amazon RDS a good solution?
2. The web server is relatively stateless except for some custom log files and the ajax cache files.  What's a good way to scale to multiple web servers?  I guess the custom log files can be moved to a reliable shared file system or DB but not sure what to do about the AJAX cache file coherency across multiple servers.  (I dont care about losing /var/log/* if web server dies)
3. For performance it might be cheaper to go with larger instance with more cores and memory but eventually I would need redundancy so wondering what's the best way to do this cheaply.

thanks

Comment: Should me moved to Serverfault

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/11739/lamp-server-performance-tips) post. there is plenty of presentations on the net discussing scalability. few things i suggest to keep in mind:

- plan early for the data sharding [even if you are not going to do it immediately]
- try using mechanisms like memcached to limit number of queries sent to the database
- prepare to serve static content from other domain, in the longer run - from ngin-x-alike server and  later CDN

redundancy - depends on your needs. is 'read-only' mode acceptable for your site? if so - go with mysql replication + rsync of static files and in case of failover have your site work in that mode till you recover the master node. if you need high availability - then take a look either at drbd replication [at least for mysql] or setup with automated promotion of slave server to become master node.

you might find following interesting:

- http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2011/08/mysql-mha-support-for-multi-master.html
- http://mysqlperformanceblog.com
- http://highscalability.com
- http://google.com - search for scalability, lamp, failover... there are tones of case studies and horror stories from the trench lines :-]

Comment: Thanks.  If I run drdb, are writes ACID compliant?  In fact I'm not even sure if the disk in a cloud instance is really ACID compliant.  When the block device says done writing is it really done?  I have pretty heavy writes from each user so read only mode not acceptable.  Right now ACID and high availability is my main concern.  In the worst case performance can be bought by paying more dollars and bump up the instance.  thx again

Comment: depends how paranoid you are. indeed with virtualization [cloud] you have less security, storage can lie to you [your own raid controller in physical server with battery backed cache lies to you too.. and oh - horror it can loose your data .. i've lost recently ~128MB of data.. because controller crashed]. if you care mostly about keeping data safe - think about group commits and synchronous replication.. between different availability zones [you'll get a big performance hit]. it's all trade-off between performance/willingness to loose data/cost and level of complication.

Comment: @Limbeh: DRBD has 3 protocols, A to B. A acknowledges writes right away. C waits for the remote disk. As always, whether all your layers (filesystem, volume management, ...) support disk barriers, and whether the device actually has done what it says it has done, is another story altogether. See http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-replication-protocols.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a scaleable platform such as Amazon Web Services.  You can start out with a micro instance and configure load balancing to fire up more instances as needed.

Once you determine average resource requirements you can then resize your image to larger or smaller depending on your needs.

http://aws.amazon.com
http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2011/06/26/creating-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-linux-lamp-stack/
http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2011/09/11/how-to-use-amazon-rds-relation-database-service-to-host-mysql/

Amazon allows you to either load balance or change instance size based off demand.